# Trouble understanding "また何処かで会えると 素敵ですね"

Tags: translation

This is what a friend said to me in response to my wishing him a happy birthday on Facebook. The topic/subject omission is often my biggest problem understanding Japanese, as I have trouble discerning what the implied topic/subject is. My best attempt is,

> "If we could meet again somewhere it would be great!"

But I am not that confident. For all I can tell, it could be

> "If we could meet somewhere again it would be a great place!"

Or something else entirely. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Notice that in "it would be great", the subject is also implied :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first hunch is the correct one.

It'd be like saying in English, "It would be great if we could meet again somewhere."

The way it's phrased sounds like the person doesn't know when-and particularly where-you will be able to meet again. If it were the latter of your guesses it would probably be emphasized for clarity, like ～素敵なところですね

Comment: Thanks! Yea, he studied abroad at my school and now he's back in Japan, so that makes sense.